# Issue with xml parsing to get child tag values in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing

I want to parse the dynamically generated xml which do not have any predefined structure for the xml file. My Xml looks like,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <metadata>
    <control for="9bd2f8fd2421eb0b0a410feaa1f482c50551486a" name="first-name" type="input" datatype="string">
                    <resources lang="en">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <help />
                            <hint>Your first or given name
                            </hint>
                            <alert />
                    </resources>
                    <resources lang="fr">
                            <label>Pr├â┬⌐nom</label>
                            <help />
                            <hint>
                                    Votre pr├â┬⌐nom
                            </hint>
                                    <alert />
                    </resources>
                    <value>Rahul</value>
            </control>

<control for="9bd2f8fd2421eb0b0a410feaa1f482c50551486b" name="last-name" type="input" datatype="string">
                    <resources lang="en">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <help />
                            <hint>Your last name
                            </hint>
                            <alert />
                    </resources>
                    <resources lang="fr">
                            <label>Pr├â┬⌐nom</label>
                            <help />
                            <hint>
                                    Votre pr├â┬⌐nom
                            </hint>
                                    <alert />
                    </resources>
                    <value>Sharma</value>
            </control>
    </metadata>
```

From the above xml I need to get the following details, Name attribute in the controller tag and content of the label and value tags. So I tried as follows,

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.xml");
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(fis);
        Node objects = doc.getDocumentElement();
        for (Node object = objects.getFirstChild(); object != null; object = object.getNextSibling()) {
            if (object instanceof Element) {
                Element e = (Element)object;
                System.out.println(e.getTagName());
                if (e.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("control")) {
                    String name = e.getAttribute("name");
                    System.out.println("It's a " + name + " control!");
                } 
               else {
                  System.out.println("I don't know what a " + e.getTagName() + " is for.");
                }
            }
        }
```

With above code I am able to get the name attribute in the controller tag. Now how can I get the content of label and value tags.

I need the following output,

```
name: first-name
label: First Name
value: Rahul


name: last-name
label: Last Name
value: Sharma
```

Comment: There are several tutorials for you you have to go through. like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/),  [this](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html), [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html),[this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/07/31/java-xml-dom-parser-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code iterates only through the control elements (as you are using the `getFirstChild, getNextSibling()`), so once "inside" the control element you need to retrieve its correct descendants (label and value). One way of doing is by calling getElementsByTagName for label and value.

```
if (e.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("control")) {
    String name = e.getAttribute("name");
    System.out.println("It's a " + name + " control!");

    NodeList labels = e.etElementsByTagName("label");
    for (int i = 0;i<labels.getLength();i++) {
        Element labelE = (Element)labels.item(i);
        String label = labelE.getTextContent();
        //do something with the label content;
    }
    ....
    NodeList values = e.etElementsByTagName("value");
    Element valueE = (Element)values.item(0); //seems you always have only one value element
    String value = valueE.get.getTextContent();
    ...
}
```

Your xml have multiple resources tags so multiple labels, you need to decide how to deal with it. You could for example retrieve first the resource tag and check their lang attribute to process only the EN ones. Or take always the first label. It is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.xml");
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(fis);
    NodeList controls = doc.getElementsByTagName("control");
    for (int i = 0; i < controls.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element)controls.item(i);
        System.out.println(element.getAttribute("name"));
        NodeList resources = element.getElementsByTagName("resources");
        for (int j = 0; j < resources.getLength(); j++) {
            Element resource = (Element) resources.item(j);
            System.out.println(resource.getAttribute("lang"));
            NodeList contents = resource.getChildNodes();
            for (int k = 0; k < contents.getLength(); k++) {
                Node item2 = contents.item(k);
                if (item2 instanceof Element) {
                    Element content = (Element)item2;
                    String tagName = content.getTagName();
                    if (content.getTextContent() != null && !content.getTextContent().isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println(tagName + ":" + content.getTextContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        NodeList values = element.getElementsByTagName("value");
        if (values.getLength() > 0) {
            Element value = (Element) values.item(0);
            System.out.println(value.getTextContent());
        }
    }
```

or generante xsd for you xml:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="metadata">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="control" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="resources" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="label"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="help"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="hint"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="alert"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="lang" use="optional"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="for" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="datatype" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

generate java Class using JAXB command:

```
xjc test.xsd
```

and use this for read values:

```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Metadata.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Metadata retorno = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File("test.xml")), Metadata.class).getValue();
    List<Metadata.Control> controls = retorno.getControl();
    for (Metadata.Control control : controls) {
        System.out.println(control.getName());
        List<Metadata.Control.Resources> resources = control.getResources();
        for (Metadata.Control.Resources resource : resources) {
            System.out.println(resource.getLabel());
            System.out.println(resource.getHint());
        }
        System.out.println(control.getValue());
    }
```